# ruby or operator behaving differently inside initialise method

Tags: ruby, instance-variables

fairly new to programming and came across the following code which does gives the intended result, that is it stores the object in the instance variable if passed as an argumnet or defaults to generating a new object and storing that. but the syntax is using an or(||) operator which as i understood always returns a boolean. so is it behaving differently or there is more to or/and operators?

```
def initialize(args = {})`
 @sms = args[:sms]              || Messenger.new
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The or operator in ruby does not "return" a boolean: it evalutes to the first expression if the first expression is truthy (a term which means everything but `false` and `nil`), otherwise it evalutes to the latter

```
5 || nil => 5
nil || 5 => 5
false || nil => nil
nil || false => false
```

Comment: got you, just checked in irb and you are right. so because so far i've only used || with comparative operators ruby was actually just evaluating that comparison and || operator just evaluated  to result of that comparison(if left side is true then true else whatever the right side is). just for my sanity check, does that kind of make sense?

Comment: Yes, you probably until now used it superficially but that worked anyway in your cases. But this is the right way to think about it

Comment: my pleasure sir <3

Answer (score 0):

in ruby, everything can be evaluated as an expression, and an expression will return a value

so `||` and even `&&` do not return a boolean it will return a truthy or falsy value

in the case of || it will check if the first expression is truthy if not it will go to the next one, then the next one, if no truthy value is found it will return the last one which will be falsy as well

```rb
irb(main):004:0> nil ||  "true value" || 0
=> "true value"

irb(main):006:0> nil || false || "true value" || 0 || true
=> "true value"
```

in the case of `&&` it will do the opposite, it will return the first falsy value it can find

```rb
irb(main):001:0> nil && false && "true value" && 0 && true
=> nil
```

and the if condition will understand truthy and falsy values which will be what these logical operators return

```rb
rb(main):007:0> if "true"
irb(main):008:1> puts "true"
irb(main):009:1> else
irb(main):010:1> puts "false"
irb(main):011:1> end
true

irb(main):017:0> if nil
irb(main):018:1> puts "true"
irb(main):019:1> else
irb(main):020:1> puts "false"
irb(main):021:1> end
false
```

Comment: thankyou, i better understand it now....appreciate your help